# Nhibernate HQL SQL Server 2005 / 2008 CONTAINSTABLE

Tags: c#, java, .net, nhibernate, hibernate

do you know anyway how I to use CONTAINSTABLEvia HQL? I need to use CONTAINSTABLE, not just CONTAINS. Currently I am using a SQL-query, but I need to use the multi-query feature which is not avaiable for SQL right now.

If there is no such thing, would I be able to extend the MSSQL dialect? Or would that require to modify the core of NH?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a NHibernate patch that will add support for custom SQL queries in a MultiQuery (see NH-2495 on http://jira.nhforge.org).